# Mapinfo Conversion Plugins

Tags: convert, mapinfo, land-cover

I have created a land classification using QGIS in Geotiff format and need to convert this to Mapinfo format.

I tried to used the conversion tool file type (Northwood Classified Grid Format .grc /.tab) but the output file is .grc and .aux.

Please advise on how to covert this files to a Mapinfo *.grc *.tab files in QGIS.

Thanks,

Comment: Is your format one the supported ones https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mapinfo-l/J_ZyKISr3ww/0vz65O8x-qYJ? MapInfo creates the .tab file when raster file is imported for the first time. Perhaps grids behave similarly and you do not need to create .tab by other means.

Answer (score 1):

MapInfo supports GeoTiff, just use File > Open and change the 'Files of Type' dropdown to 'Raster Images'. This should generate a tab file for your GeoTiff.